# Отправка почты через SMTP

Tags: c#, smtp

Использую следующий фрагмент кода для отправки сообщения, почему при отправке сообщения программа зависает? Что я сделал неверно?

```
public static void SendMail()
{
    System.Net.NetworkCredential crdSupport = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("easy_send_mail", "password");
    SmtpClient smtpConfirmation = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 465);
    smtpConfirmation.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtpConfirmation.Credentials = crdSupport;

    MailMessage mmConfirmation = new MailMessage();
    mmConfirmation.From = new MailAddress("easy_send_mail@mail.ru", "EasySendMail");
    mmConfirmation.To.Add("test@mail.ru");
    mmConfirmation.Subject = "EasySendMail test subject";
    mmConfirmation.Body = "EasySendMail test body";
    smtpConfirmation.Send(mmConfirmation);
}
```

Comment: Почитайте про `async/await`...

Comment: А доступ до mail.ru у вас есть?

Comment: Ну, я зарегистрировал новый ящик easy_send_mail и вместо Password писал пароль от него

Comment: Это понятно, но есть ли доступ у вашей программы к smtp.mail.ru на порт 465? Попробуйте создать TcpClient и посмотреть, получится ли успешно соединиться.